# Using CMFCPropertyGridCtrl, How to avoid tips when the mouse moves to the edit box with too long content?

Tags: mfc

Using `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl`,
How to avoid tips when the mouse moves to the edit box with too long content?

Comment: Updated my answer with some more details for you.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at using:

[`CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::AlwaysShowUserToolTip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridctrl-class?view=msvc-160#alwaysshowusertooltip)

It accepts a `BOOL` parameter.

---

## Additional Information

I had a look at the source code for the property grid and I noticed the following:

```
void CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::Init()
{
    CRect rectDummy;
    rectDummy.SetRectEmpty();

    if (GetGlobalData()->m_hcurStretch == NULL)
    {
        GetGlobalData()->m_hcurStretch = AfxGetApp()->LoadCursor(AFX_IDC_HSPLITBAR);
    }

    if (GetGlobalData()->m_hcurStretchVert == NULL)
    {
        GetGlobalData()->m_hcurStretchVert = AfxGetApp()->LoadCursor(AFX_IDC_VSPLITBAR);
    }

    InitHeader();

    HDITEM hdItem;
    hdItem.mask = HDI_TEXT | HDI_FORMAT;
    hdItem.fmt = HDF_LEFT;
    hdItem.pszText = _T("Property");
    hdItem.cchTextMax = 100;

    GetHeaderCtrl().InsertItem(0, &hdItem);

    hdItem.pszText = _T("Value");
    hdItem.cchTextMax = 100;

    GetHeaderCtrl().InsertItem(1, &hdItem);

    m_wndScrollVert.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBS_VERT, rectDummy, this, AFX_ID_SCROLL_VERT);

    m_ToolTip.Create(this, TTS_ALWAYSTIP);
    m_ToolTip.Activate(TRUE);
    if (GetGlobalData()->m_nMaxToolTipWidth != -1)
    {
        m_ToolTip.SetMaxTipWidth(GetGlobalData()->m_nMaxToolTipWidth);
    }

    m_ToolTip.SetWindowPos(&wndTop, -1, -1, -1, -1, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOSIZE);

    m_IPToolTip.Create(this);

    CWnd* pWndParent = GetParent();
    m_bControlBarColors = pWndParent == NULL || !pWndParent->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CDialog));

    AdjustLayout();
    CreateBoldFont();
    CalcEditMargin();
}
```

I don't have access to the header file so I do not know if the `m_ToolTip` variable is public. Interestingly, when you read about the [`CMFCPropertyGridToolTipCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridtooltipctrl-class?view=msvc-160) class it does state:

> MFC automatically creates this control and uses it in the `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` Class.

If the tooltip object is not exposed, then maybe you can create your own property grid class that derives from the base class and you then may have the ability to either expose the `m_ToolTip` control or deactivate it, or do whatever it is you want to do.

---

I also see references in the code of the `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` class to:

```
m_pWndList->m_ToolTip.AddTool(m_pWndList, LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK, rectName, m_pWndList->m_nTooltipsCount + 1);
m_pWndList->m_nTooltipsCount ++;
```

It might be worth examining the **MFC code** to see where and how the tooltips are used and then you will be better able to override their behaviour in your derived class(es).

MFC Code path on my PC:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\atlmfc\src\mfc

---

### How To Do

- Display ClassWizard:

[image]

- Add a MFC Class:

[image]

- Give it a name and select the property grid control as the base class:

[image]

You would use this class to define your grid control and now you can add a public method:

```
void CMyPropertyGrid::DeactivateToolTips()
{
    m_ToolTip.Activate(FALSE);
}
```

In theory, if you call this `DeactivateToolTips` method at the right time it should disable the tips. Keep in mind that the tool tip control handles the tips for many elements so the final solution might not be this simple but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: This switch toggles between two modes of operation: Either show a tooltip unconditionally, or show a tooltip only when the display text is truncated. It won't help the OP solve their issue. It's understandable to not know what this switch does, given that MFC's documentation is completely useless.

Comment: @IInspectable Oops. Sorry about that. I did try to find an explanation and as you say the help is useless.

Comment: AlwaysShowUserToolTip(FALSE)  Without any effect, tips will still be displayed when the mouse moves up

Comment: @wsy @Illnspectable already said that in his comment. This is why I added some extra info about deriving your own class and deactivating the tooltip control `m_ToolTip`.

Comment: m_ToolTip is a protected variable

Comment: @wsy Ok, so my suggested is valid. Create your own class which derives from the base class, then you have access to `m_ToolTip` and you can add a public method to "deactivate" it.

Comment: @Andrew Truckle Thank you very much for your help！